# Examples of proper classes besides the universe and Russell's class

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there any other interesting proper class besides the universe $U$ and Russell's class $R$?

- $U=\{x:x=x\}$
- $R=\{x:x\notin x\}$

**Background**: I'm studying the appendix on elementary set theory from the book *General Topology* by John L. Kelley, but I'm not sure if allowing proper classes is useful or not. I'm not sure if I should continue with Morse-Kelley set theory or revert to Zermelo-Fraenkel.

Comment: The class of [ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number).

Comment: In NBG, we have $R = U$ (don't know about Morse-Kelley). A useful proper class [in NBG] that isn't the entire universe is the class of ordinals. Sometimes, allowing proper classes is useful, sometimes not.

Comment: @Daniel $R=U$ also holds in $MK$. $MK$ is $NBG$ with one difference: The comprehension schema allows quantification over proper classes.

Comment: @Francesco After typing three different answers to your question, I now decided to ignore it: I haven't read Kelley's book, but it probably won't matter whether you take $ZF$ or $MK$ as your background theory. To avoid unforeseen trouble, I'd advice you to stick with $MK$ nonetheless. Being familiar with $MK$, the transition to $ZFC$ then merely is a matter of minutes (all you have to do is to forget about classes and replace global choice with your favorite version in $ZFC$).

Comment: No other example besides the class of ordinals? I don't know what an ordinal is, so I'm not really encouraged to continue with proper classes...

Answer (score 2):

Examples of proper classes: the class of all $5$-element sets, the class of all groups, the class of all complete ordered fields, the class of all topological spaces . . .

Answer (score 0):

The set of all pure sets $\mathrm{V}$ (a pure set is a set where all elements are pure sets or $\{\}$). This is very, very, VERY important in set theory and model theory, large cardinal axioms, and more. In fact, it is intuitive to say that a set is a proper class if and only if it has a class bijection onto $\mathrm{V}$.

Comment: Note that this [old] question mentions that the background theory is Kelley--Morse, where all the sets are pure sets. And while you never claimed that formally proper classes have bijections with V, it is consistent that there is no bijection between the ordinals and V itself...

Comment: Ok, then is the constructable universe ok?

Comment: That's a slightly better example, yes. Note that in the comments the OP says that they do not know what is an ordinal, so I doubt that this would be a much better example in that case.

Comment: Good point... what about the set of all cardinalities $\tav$?

Comment: Possibly better, as it is easier to explain intuitively. But, again, might be a bit problematic for someone doesn't know what an ordinal is.